# Running code just before </body> instead of waiting for DOM ready/DOMcontentloaded event

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there any drawback to putting code (which will interact with the DOM, adding event listeners and so on) just before the closing `</body>` tag?

```
<!-- all the HTML comes before this -->
(function() {
  do_stuff_with_the_DOM();
})();
</body>
```

It seems to work in my own tests, but I never see this method used in tutorials, code examples, or other people's projects. Is there a reason not to do it? Are there edge cases that only seem to pop up when you begin using this in production and see many page views across a variety of browsers?

My project doesn't use jQuery or any other toolkit, and I'm aware of the alternatives that mimic jQuery's `$(document).ready()` functionality. Do I really need to use one of those? (It should go without saying, but I'm looking to run the code before `window.load`.)

Note that the code I want to run (`do_stuff_with_the_DOM()` in the example above) would be defined in an external script file, if that makes a difference.

Comment: As long as you put the JS-code within a script-tag, that is actually recommended.

Comment: DOM listener and </body> are the same. Just to note - JS just before </body> will execute before the DOM listener is triggered.

Comment: @crolpa DOM listener and </body> are *not* the same. See my answer below.

Comment: Of course not :) With the example of the OP the result would be almost identical. A good thing to note is that an external script file is cached by the browser, suitable if needed on other pages. Use this info to help wade through those answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your JavaScript code in the place that makes the most sense for what it needs to do. In most cases, you need your js to attach events to DOM objects, which is hard to imagine if those DOM objects don't exist when the js is running. So putting it at the bottom of the html is a sensible, simple, and common approach. Is it the best? [That's arguable.](http://web.archive.org/web/20100824040759/http://web-graphics.com/mtarchive/001635.php)

Another approach is to attach your JavaScript to the various events that different browsers fire when the DOM is fully loaded. There is nothing wrong with this, although detractors don't like that it's often done in a way that requires an additional blocking HTTP request in the `head` element.

Event *delegation* offers a third approach that lets you attach events to parent elements (such as `body`) very early, and when appropriate child events exist the events will fire as if they had been attached to those elements all along. It's a very cool approach with [theoretically the best early-loading performance](http://encosia.com/dont-let-jquerys-document-ready-slow-you-down/) of any of the above, but has pitfalls in that not all events bubble all the way to the top, like you might expect, and that it often tempts you to separate your JavaScript into multiple chunks, which can violate separation of content and behavior.

Answer (score 0):

### In General

Putting code just before `</body>` should always be the aim.

Its highly recommended, as the download of scripts (if requesting external JavaScript files) blocks parallel downloading (i.e. whilst a script is downloading, nothing else - be it another script or an image for example - can be downloaded at the same time).

The only time you should have an issue with this, is in something like a poor CMS system where you need to have jQuery in-place in the `<head>` in order for some of its scripts to work.

### Using inline JavaScript

1. Adding inline JavaScript (or inline CSS code) to a page is generally [considered bad practice](http://css.dzone.com/news/why-inline-css-and-javascript-) as, for one, its a merging of concerns (i.e. you no longer have true separation between HTML/CSS/JS).
2. I cannot think of a negative performance issue if you did have all your code inlined - indeed Google use this as a practice (they load all their JavaScript in a bit comment (so that it isn't parsed) and then `eval()` elements of this blob of "text" as and when they need to.
3. I would note however, that its unlikely nowadays that you'll have many pages that don't at some point have a requirement on at least one external JavaScript file (be that JQuery, Mootools, Underscore of Backbone). In which case, as you will always have at least one external file (unless you're going to Google route), then you might as well put both external references AND inline code together... at the bottom. Creating consistency.

### References

- [Yahoo Developer Network best practices](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#js_bottom)
- [Google Page Speed - Defer the loading of JavaScript](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/payload.html#DeferLoadingJS)

Comment: Why should inline JS be the aim? Can you back that up - im interested.

Comment: @crolpa Sorry yes sure, I've added more including a reference.

Comment: @crolpa how did you interpret this answer to mean *inline* js? I don't see it.

Comment: @beardtwizzle Thanks for the addition. Now putting JS inline aids in reducing additional requests but if you have the Javascript included on on every page, that extra request in turn will be cached by the browser - providing a lot more benefit to the end user.

Comment: @beardtwizzle. If the JS is not *inline* (as in embedded in the html) than it's not solving any "parallel downloading" issue. There's no difference between that and using a DOM listener. :)

Comment: @crolpa - was typing my more detailed edit - I hadn't noted the reference to inlining

Comment: great :) Not relevant at all but personally I'm not a fan of sprinkling JS *inline* throughout a website. Besides mixing languages, if that JS is combined into one relevant file its more efficient to download once - really depends on the individual case.

Comment: @crolpa - +1 for 'really depends on the individual case'... run Gmail through some of these 'best practices' tools and you'll see 'red' all over the place - yet I think its a damn good app!

Comment: Gmail does javascript loading correctly in my opinion. It is essentially one html page, thus *inline* js is the way it goes, with a few external librarys throw in. I'll go find my green highlighter ;)